# Sending the parent object to the Box File Upload API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, box, rest-client

I'm attempting to use the Box File Upload API to send a file to Box.com from a Ruby on Rails application.  However, I keep getting a bad request response that says parent is a missing parameter.

Here is their documentation:
https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#upload-a-file

Here is their curl example:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
-F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
-F file=@myfile.jpg
```

I'm attempting to use RailsClient to do this in my app and here are the two ways I've tried:

```
RestClient.post(BASE_CONTENT_URL,{ :name => "randompdf.pdf", :parent => {:id => 0}, :myfile => file }, { :Authorization => "Bearer #{NEW_TOKEN}" })
```

&

```
@parent = Struct.new(:id)
@parent.id = 0
RestClient.post(BASE_CONTENT_URL,{ :name => "randompdf.pdf", :parent => @parent, :myfile => file }, { :Authorization => "Bearer #{NEW_TOKEN}" })
```

I get the same error attempting to do it via Postman as well.  Box's Community Forum and Support resources haven't gotten back to me so I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
attributes = {name: #{unique_name}, parent: { id: 0 }}
box_response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                       url: BASE_UPLOAD_URL + "/content",
                       payload: { attributes: attributes.to_json,
                       file: file},
                       headers: {Authorization: "Bearer #{NEW_TOKEN}"})
```